# Подгрузка контента

Tags: php, javascript

Вот [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/nb3gu/19/) весь код.
В мозиле все работает на ура, но во всех остальных не работает. Не получает значение атрибута `title` и `href`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `(e.originalEvent.originalTarget)` поставьте `(e.target)` в двух местах в JS.